# Date field changing from UK to US culture upon SaveChanges (EF6.1)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework

I am using a custom overloaded SaveChanges to implement some auditing functionality.  The functionality works perfectly with the exception of some unexpected behaviour in relation to dates.  In this example I'm changing a date field value from 1st May 2014 to 2nd May 2014:

A change is made to the database here:

```
 Public Function UpdateTask(request As DataSourceRequest, ThisTask As JobTasksVM) As JsonResult
        Dim cu As ApplicationUser = GetCurrentUser()
        Dim CurrentTask = db.events.Find(ThisTask.id)

        CurrentTask.start_date = ThisTask.start '<--- 2/5/2014 (ie 2nd May 2014), was previously 1/5/2014
        CurrentTask.date = ThisTask.end
        CurrentTask.task_name = ThisTask.Title

        db.SaveChanges(cu.Employee_id)
    End Function
```

This is intercepted by my custom SaveChanges:

```
 Public Overloads Function SaveChanges(userID As Integer) As Integer

    For Each entry As dbentityentry In Me.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(Function(e) e.State <> EntityState.Unchanged)
            Dim startOriginal As DateTime = entry.OriginalValues.Item("start_date")
            Dim StartCurrent As DateTime = entry.CurrentValues.Item("start_date")
            etc....
```

The bizarre thing is that whilst CurrentTask.start_date that is committed clearly shows the correct (UK) date of 2/5/2014 (2nd May 2014) the values within the overloaded SaveChanges are:

startOriginal: 5/1/2014 (ie 5th Jan 2014)  <-- seems to have changed to US culture

startCurrent: 2/5/2014 (ie 2nd May 2014)  <---as expected

I need to use the Original values in my audit functionality so this is causing a problem.  I have also tried:

```
entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entry.GetDatabaseValues)
```

But this also loads in the erroneous (ie US format 5/1/2014) into the start_date field.

I've checked all the culture settings on the system and they are all correctly English-UK.  This behaviour seems fundamentally inconsistent - am I missing something?!
Thanks

Comment: Thank you for this.  You made me go back and look at the value of 'ThisTask.Start' and it appears this is coming across in US date format.  Converting to UK format appears to solve the problem.  I've now learnt that intellisense is always in US date format (culture invariant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTime` types do not have a format, they are simply a value (number of ticks since 1/1/0001).

You did not say where you are seeing the "wrong" format, whether `ToString()` output or in intellisense.  If you use `ToString` to the Output window, you should see the UK format since `ToString` will use/respect the local culture setting of the computer.

Intellisense is culture agnostic and tries to use an unambiguous format: `MM/dd/yyyy`.  This is the same "format" or order you have to use when creating a `DateTime` var from a literal:

```
Dim dt As DateTime = #1/5/2014#      ' e.g. MM/dd/yyyy
' same as:
Dim dt As New DateTime(1, 5, 2014)   ' mm, dd, yyyy
```

This is `InvariantCulture` (not US).  When you hold the mouse over the var, the VB IDE will use the same order.  It tries to make clear it is using the required literal/InvariantCulture format by displaying it **with** the hashes: `#1/5/2014#`.

```
Dim dt As DateTime = #2/11/2011#
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString)
```

In the US, `2/11/2011` will display based on the culture
In the UK, it will be `11/2/2011`
Intellisense will be `#2/11/2011#`

Comment: Thank you yes - this makes perfect sense.  It appear my MVC HTMLhelper is choking on UK date formats and whilst displaying them correctly is not behaving as expected on the AJAX post. (possibly in the JSON transformation).  Clearly my ignorance, but thank you for clarifying - I have learnt something.

Comment: I am sure it is confusing for the non MM/dd parts of the world, but it would be more problematic if after creating a date var, intellisense immediately displayed it in a different order.

Comment: For others maybe having the same issue, it turned out that my culture in Kendo needed setting (<script>
kendo.culture("en-GB");
</script>) in _layout.vbhtml